# To those who believe Isaiah 49 is Messianic and in the deity of Christ, how do you understand Isaiah 49:5?

Tags: christology, prophecy, isaiah

There are many people who see Isaiah 49 as Messianc, mainly because it mentions the servant as being a light for the gentiles,

Isaiah 49:6(ESV)

> he says: “It is too light a thing that you should be my servant
> to raise up the tribes of Jacob
> and to bring back the preserved of Israel; I will make you as a light for the nations,
> that my salvation may reach to the end of the earth.”

But in the verse before it states that, the servant was formed from the womb.

Isaiah 49:5(ESV)

> And now the Lord says,
> he who **formed** me from the womb to be his servant, to bring Jacob back to him;
> and that Israel might be gathered to him— for I am honored in the eyes of the Lord,
> and my God has become my strength—

This seems like it is being stated that the servant was formed in the sense of creation in the womb. So what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Incarnation of Christ**  It is true that the Bible describes *every person* as someone who was made by the special creative Hand of God while in the mother's womb:

> (13) Thou hast possessed my reins; Thou hast covered me in my mother's womb. (14) I will praise Thee for I am fearfully and wonderfully made; marvelous are Thy works, and that my soul knows quite well.
> (15) My substance was not hid from Thee when I was made in secret, and curiously wrought in the lowest parts of the earth. (16) Thy eyes did see my substance yet being imperfect, and in thy book all my members were written, which in continuance were fashioned when as yet there was none of them. (Psalm 139:13-16)

The conception of a baby is a miraculous handiwork of an amazing Creator. ( With the womb figuratively described here as *in the lowest parts of the earth*.)

**Virgin Birth** But the birth of Jesus was a special creation: a birth in a virgin womb without conception. It was the method God used for Jesus (God) becoming man so He could eventually become the sinless, redemptive Lamb of God to take away the sins of the world. (John 1:29-34). If Jesus was born naturally, of Joseph and Mary, He would have been tainted with the "fallen, sinful nature of mankind", and that would have disqualifies Him from being the ***perfect sacrifice.***

> The LORD has called me from the womb; from the bowels of my mother hath He made ***mention of my Name***. (Isaiah 49:1)

Notice the naming of Jesus by the angel Gabriel when he first announced the *virgin birth* to Mary:

> And the angel said unto her, "Fear not, Mary, for you have found favor with God. (31) And behold, you will conceive in your womb, and bring forth a son and shall call ***His name 'Jesus'***, (32) And He shall be great, and shall be called 'the Son of the Highest...' " (Luke 30-32)

**For a Reason** This miraculous virgin birth was *for a reason*, it wasn't just another birth, or a birth of a mere prophet or priest:

> Now, saith the LORD that formed Me from the womb to be ***His servant*** to bring Jacob back to Him...And He said, "It is a light thing that Thou shouldest be My Servant to raise up the tribes of Jacob...I will also give Thee for a ***Light to the Gentiles***, that you may be My salvation unto the ends of the earth! (Isaiah 49:5-6)

All this coincides with the famous verse often quoted: John 3:16! ***For God so loved the world***.  And it agrees with the Command of Jesus just before His Ascension, ***Go you therefore and teach all nations...*** (Matthew 28:19; see also Acts 1:8)

So we can see why many biblical commenters consider this chapter 49 in Isaiah to be ***Messianic***.